# IF variable = 'something' INSERT IF variable = 'somethingelse' INSERT

Tags: sql-server-2005, if-statement, sql-insert

I have an input variable that is set based on what a user chooses, then based on what this variable is set to, the data will be "different".

The options are 'Number' or 'Date'.

So if the user enters 'Number', the will get the data by Number, if they choose 'Date' they will get the data by date.

There is a lot going on in the procedure but where I'm having trouble is the end.  Based on what the variable is set to, I have to insert into a `#ResultsTable`.

So I need help with my IF statement, what I have is...

```
IF @Input = 'Number'
BEGIN
   Insert records into #ResultsTable
END
ELSE 
IF @Input = 'Date'
   Insert records into #ResultsTable
END
SELECT * FROM #ResultsTable
```

So the error I'm getting is when I run the stored procedure where the `@Input` variable is 'Date', it says

> Invalid object name '#ResultsTable'.

It works fine when the `@Input` variable is 'Number'.

Comment: do you need a "BEGIN' after 'Date' and before 'INSERT'?

Answer (score 0):

Should the query not be:

```
IF @Input = 'Number' 
  BEGIN Insert records into #ResultsTable 
END 
ELSE IF @Input = 'Date' 
  BEGIN Insert records into #ResultsTable 
END 
SELECT * FROM #ResultsTable
```

I think you forgot the 'BEGIN' after `@Input = 'Date'`

Comment: Ok, I added the 'BEGIN' and it's still not working, it gives me a some 'rows affected' but after the 4th one, that's where I get the error.

Comment: If some rows are inserting, but it fails on a certain row, sounds like a data issue.  Check what data you are trying to insert in the 5th row (if 4 inserted correctly).

Comment: Ok, now I have an entirely new problem.  It's not analyzing the ELSE statement at all.  I'm sure its something stupid like an END in the wrong spot.  Thank you so much Orin for all your help.  Looks like I'll be staring at code for a while ugh!